# How Do I query Multiple tables on Nodejs & PostgreSql?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I'm a bit lost here. I currently have 2 tables named, todo and sales. I would like to insert data into both of them simultaneously, but there seems to be a 'cannot insert multiple commands into a prepared statement' error occurring. Is there any other way I can do this?

```
app.post("/mytodo", async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const { user_name, user_email, user_address, total_sale_value, repeat_visit_sales_value } = req.body;
      const newTodo = await pool.query(
      "INSERT INTO todo (user_name, user_email, user_address) VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING *; INSERT INTO sales (total_sale_value, repeat_visit_sales_value) VALUES ($4, $5, $6) RETURNING *;",  [
        user_name, user_email, user_address, total_sale_value, repeat_visit_sales_value 
      ] );
       res.json(newTodo.rows[0]);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using transactions.

```
BEGIN; first_query; second_query; third_query; COMMIT;
```

here is the link for [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/tutorial-transactions.html) of PostgreSQL

here is the [link](https://node-postgres.com/features/transactions) for `node-postgres` version

Comment: I don't think this works with express, maybe.